# On Gentoo, how do I rebuild all packages depended on some other package?

Tags: package-management, compiling, gentoo, emerge

I made mistake and changed perl non-threaded version to threaded by unmerge first, change `USE` flags to include ithreads and emerge perl again. Now most packages depending on perl are broken. How do I rebuild them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On way is to use `equery`'s `depends` function to get the list of things that depend on a package.

```
# equery depends perl
```

If you want to rebuild all of them, try something like:

```
# emerge -a --oneshot `equery depends perl|awk '{print " ="$1}'`
```

You'll have issues with that if you have packages installed that were removed from the portage tree, so a sync and world update beforehand is a good idea.

For this specific case, you might also want to look at `app-admin/perl-cleaner` - it has specific features to rebuild perl modules.

Answer (score 3):

Try using **`revdep-rebuild`** (from `app-portage/gentoolkit` package, same as `equery`). It is a tool that scans the system for broken dependencies (like missing shared libraries) and rebuilds the packages that have broken dependencies. An advantage of this compared to [Mat's method](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21888/on-gentoo-how-do-i-rebuild-all-packages-depended-on-some-other-package/21889#21889) is that in most cases you don't need to rebuild *all* packages that depend upon some other one.

Comment: `revdep-rebuild` is first thing I tried, but it can't handle this case because library (libperl.so) is present but missing some symbols.

Comment: Hmm, strange - I thought it already handled `USE` dependency information correctly. Anyway, since it is a problem with `perl`, there is a special tool for such job: `app-admin/perl-cleaner`.

Comment: I've tried `perl-cleaner --all` but it didn't rebuild `vim` which is linked against `libperl.so`.

Comment: If vim is still broken after that, you should file a bug report.

Comment: But make sure it really is - `vim` depends on `perl` *only if* it is built with `perl` useflag! (That is also a reason why Mat's method could force far too many rebuilds.)