# List all packages on a Gentoo system, which were not recompiled since a date

Tags: package-management, logs, gentoo, maintenance

A system change (like gcc, perl, python, qt... update) can demand that many packages have to be rebuilt.

This ends often in a world rebuild with

```
# emerge --ask --emptytree --verbose @system
# emerge --ask --emptytree --verbose @world
```

In a world rebuild with 2000 packages it is likely, that the merge failed for tens or hundreds and one has to fix the problems.

Technically one could rebuild the `world` after fixing the problems, but this takes very long.

**How can I list all packages which have not been successfully rebuilt since the day `$DATE`?**

What I tried so far:

```
# create a sorted list with all packages built till $DATE=2017-05-30
qlop -ld 2000-01-01 -d $DATE | cut -d ">" -f 4 | sort
```

But this list contains

- all versions and not only the latest one
- packages which were removed from the system
- packages which have been rebuilt successfully after `$DATE`

Comment: See [Packages to rebuild after upgrading gcc on gentoo systems](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/165105/packages-to-rebuild-after-upgrading-gcc-on-gentoo-systems) for the acceptable practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emerge `eix`

Then

```
eix-update
eix '-I*' --format '<installedversions:DATESORT>' | sort -n | cut -f2-3
```

will give you a list of installed packages (with slots if necessary), sorted by installation date. e.g.:
`...
 15/11/17 12:34:51       net-misc/rsync
 15/11/17 12:35:29       dev-libs/libuv
 15/11/17 12:35:58       app-editors/vim-core
 15/11/17 12:36:32       dev-python/pycairo
 15/11/17 12:37:17       app-editors/vim
 15/11/17 12:37:49       dev-util/eric`

Save this to a file, remove all packages emerged after your cutoff date, edit out the timestamps, and you have the list of packages to re-emerge