# How to recompile everything efficiently on a Gentoo Linux system?

Tags: compiling, upgrade, performance, gentoo, maintenance

After the upgrade from `gcc-5.x` to `gcc-6.4` all Gentoo Linux users were advised to run

```
emerge -e @world
```

which will recompile all packages on a system and takes on my i7 with 16 GB around 30 h in theory. 
This will work in some simple situations, but in many cases the task stops after say 80 of 2000 packages due to a problem at some point. The user tries to fix it and starts from zero again. I tried

```
emerge --resume --skipfirst
```

and `--keep-going` but this does not work, if the problem was not caused by the first package.

A second problem is, that all packages, which are listed in `packages.provided` must be ignored. The packages.provided is important for users, who need a recent TeXlive for example and install via `tlmgr`.

My idea was to start with a list of packages which were not compiled after 2017-12-01, which is the day, I start to recompile.

```
genlop -ln --date 1999-01-01 --date 2017-12-01  | perl -ne '/>>> (.*)/ and print " =$1";'
```

Ideally the system would compile all packages which raise no error. On the next day the user can fix a problem and compiles the fixed package one after the other.

**How can I recompile all packages, which were really installed from the tree (excluding the packages.provided) without starting at point zero after each problem?**

**edit:** This is obviously no duplicate of [List all packages on a Gentoo system, which were not recompiled since a date](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/369127/list-all-packages-on-a-gentoo-system-which-were-not-recompiled-since-a-date), however its results could be help for the solution of this question.

Comment: @PiedPiper As already written in my question and your comment, the `keep-going` does not really solve the problem. But I fixed the typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

Save your start time before you begin

```
date +%s >emergestart && emerge -e --keep-going @world
```

Then when the emerge inevitably stops you can resume with this script (after fixing any problematic builds)

```
#!/bin/bash
starttime=`cat emergestart`
eix '-I*' --format '<installedversions:DATESORT>' | cut -f1,3 >tmplist
echo $starttime >>tmplist
sort -n tmplist | sed -e/$starttime/q | sed -e'/[0-9]*\t*/s///' | sort | comm -23 - <(sort omitlist) | comm -23 - <(sort /etc/portage/profile/package.provided) >buildlist
rm tmplist
emerge -a `cat buildlist` --keep-going
```

The script removes all packages from `packages.provided` from the list, and also other packages you don't want to emerge (either because they are causing problems or they don't need re-emerging) from a file called `omitlist`

Example `omitlist`:

```
sys-devel/gcc:5.4.0
sys-kernel/gentoo-sources:4.13.12
sys-kernel/gentoo-sources:4.14.2
app-cdr/cdrdao
media-gfx/kphotoalbum
virtual/libintl
virtual/libiconv
app-doc/abs-guide
app-doc/autobook
app-doc/jargon
```

You'll probably need to do several iterations of the resume script